# android studio 3.0.1 settings editor right margin (columns)

Tags: android-studio, editor, settings

I am changing default value of right margin (columns) from 100 to 255. It works fine unless I exit the Android Studio (AS). Next time, I launch AS the value comes back to 100.
It is annoying to remeber and change this every time I start AS